# Unification by transformation

Tags: f#, unification

I am writing a [unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29) algorithm in F# for use with [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) transformations using ["Term Rewriting and All That"](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1166682/?site_locale=en_GB) ([WoldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/37315354)) by Franz Baader and Tobias Nipkow. For section 4.6 Unification by transformation, it was too much math theory with the examples, and not as clear as I would have liked.

Can someone give or point out simpler examples that make use of transformations:

Delete, Decompose, Orient, Eliminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete: `t = t` is pointless and can be removed from the set of equations.

```
1 =? 1 -> nil
```

Orient: We want all equations in the form of `x =? t`, so flip any equations in the form of `t =? x`.

```
2 =? x1 -> x1 =? 2
```

Eliminate: Given `x =? t`, change all other equations to replace all instances of `x` with `t`.

```
x1 + x2 = 7, x2 = 5 -> x1 + 5 = 7, x2 = 5
```

Decompose: We need to take any functions and eliminate them to get equations in the form of `x =? t`. Note that this process technically only removes one function at a time.

```
x1 + 5 = 7 -> x1 = 2
2 * (x1 + x2) = 14 -> x1 + x2 = 7
```

Hopefully this helps.